# Stream video from Flash to HTML5

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, html, actionscript

If I have a video being streamed into flash which is doing some work with it, is it then possible to stream it out of flash and play it in the HTML5 video tag?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a swf file, I suggest you having a look at [google swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/)

Comment: I need to do some work with the video in flash, otherwise I'd just directly insert it into the HTML, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the flash content is non-interactive, try [Flabaco - www.Flash-Banner-Converter.com](http://www.flash-banner-converter.com). Its an online, SWF to video converter.

Any work done in flash on the video should appear in the converted output. If the video is long it will get truncated due to resource limitations (since its a free service).

Flabaco generates video in WebM, MP4 and OGG formats which can be embedded using the HTML5  tag.  Quality, frame rate (fps) and color are preserved well.  However sound will be lost.

Kayo.

Flabaco